# Using OR and ISNULL in Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, raster-calculator

I am using ModelBuilder for ArcGIS Desktop 10.2

I have the following code in the Raster Calcualtor which works in some cases but not in others.

```
Int(Con(IsNull("%A%")|"%A%"== 0,"%B%",float(%Max%) + "%A%"))
```

In cases that A is Null I want the code to return the value from B however it is returning a Null. I suspect there is a flaw in the OR syntax but I can't work out what is wrong.

Comment: This question suggests that the error may be the % signs around your variables. Seems to be caused by ModelBuilder.http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82889/raster-calculator-error

Comment: The % are required by model builder to refer to temporary files. ArcGIS adds them when you click on the required rasters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the OR expression. A nested Con() statement works

> Int(Con(IsNull("%A%"), %B%, Con("%A%"==0, %B%, float(%Max%) + "%A%")))

Your OR expression seems to be evaluating to NoData and receiving NoData as output. See the help [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000)